# Present UIActivityViewController in a way that Adapts Correctly to Size Class Changes

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, size-classes

The [documentation of `UIActivityViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller) says the following:

> On iPad, you must present the view controller in a popover. On iPhone and iPod touch, you must present it modally.

This does not make too much sense since we have Size Classes, and modally presented viewcontrollers adapt their appearance automatically to it (e.g. when we present something as a popover, it will by default be presented as a popover in Size Class `Regular`, and fullscreen in Size Class `Compact`).

Presenting the `UIActivityViewController` in a popover for current Size Class `Compact` (which should automatically show fullscreen) does not work, the system complains. Presenting it as a popover for current Size Class `Regular`, and then changing the Size Class via Split Mode / Multitasking results in an empty nav bar and I cannot dismiss the viewcontroller. I should notice that I embedded the `UIActivityViewController` in a navigation controller.

[image: UIActivityViewController in Split Mode]

Any suggestions how to make this responsive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must not** embed the `UIActivityViewController` in a `UINavigationController`. I know it doesn't say so in the docs, but that's the only way I got it to work. And then you can actually present it the same way as you would do with any other popover/modal view. And it adapts correctly when you active Split Mode while it is being presented.